# how to collect input data from different tabs within AngularJS application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm starting a small Angular app.
This app presents the user with one or more tabs, and collets data from user input field within each tab.
Being new to Angular, I'm struggling with collecting this data from the different tabs.
Here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>DC Quote</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-view></div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="angular-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Tab html:

```
<div ng-controller="TabController">
    <tabset>
        <tab ng-repeat="workspace in workspaces"
             heading="{{workspace.name}}"
             active=workspace.active>
            <div ng-controller="TabsChildController">
                <div>
                    <p>Enter equipment information, or upload the asset list</p>
                    {{$parent.workspace.id}} : {{ $parent.workspace.name}}
                </div>
                <input type="text" ng-model="workspace.name"/>
                User Input:
                <input type="text" ng-model="userInput"/>
            </div>
        </tab>
        <tab select="addWorkspace()">
            <tab-heading> Add Site
                <i class="icon-plus-sign"></i>
            </tab-heading>
        </tab>
        <tab select="removeWorkspace()">
            <tab-heading> Remove Selected Site
                <i class="icon-plus-sign"></i>
            </tab-heading>
        </tab>
    </tabset>
    <button type="button" ng-click="collectValuesFromEachTab()">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

Here is the application script:

```
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'ui.bootstrap'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/Quote', {templateUrl: 'tabcontrol.html', controller: 'TabController'})
      .otherwise({redirectTo: '/Quote'});
}])
    .controller("TabController", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
      console.log("This is TabController");
      var setAllInactive = function() {
        angular.forEach($scope.workspaces, function(workspace) {
          workspace.active = false;
        });
      };

      var addNewWorkspace = function() {
        var id = $scope.workspaces.length + 1;
        $scope.workspaces.push({
          id: id,
          name: "Site " + id,
          active: true
        });
      };

      $scope.workspaces =
          [
            { id: 1, name: "Site 1" ,active:true  }
          ];

      $scope.addWorkspace = function () {
        setAllInactive();
        addNewWorkspace();
      };

      $scope.removeWorkspace = function() {
        angular.forEach($scope.workspaces, function(workspace) {
          if(workspace.active){
            var index = $scope.workspaces.indexOf(workspace);
            console.log('Active Workspace id: ' + index);
            $scope.workspaces.splice(index,1);
          }
        })
      }

      $scope.collectValuesFromEachTab = function(){
        var myNumber = $scope.userInput;
        console.log($scope.userInput)
      }

    }])
    .controller("TabsChildController", ['$scope',function($scope){

    }]);
```

And here is a working (except for the input collection) plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Q3fhSQ0CNlQoXKOQKrvV

The goal is to be able to collect the data from the $scope.userInput within each tab

Comment: Have you tried with ng-model="userInput[$index]" ? Then you use the length of workspace to know the number of input and collect all input data.

Comment: Take a look at this version that removes the child controller...and puts user input on each workspace  http://plnkr.co/edit/D8QAWNoPIVgQFgUcLr9J?p=preview The child controller would be easier to just turn into a directive if you want t do a bunch of things on each instance of workspace

Comment: thanks! It works fine now:  $scope.collectValuesFromEachTab = function(){
        angular.forEach($scope.workspaces, function(workspace) {
          console.log(workspace.userInput)
        })